# Getting wrong ids from sequence with spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I am using spring data jpa to save with spring boot application with DB2. I have configured

```
 public class AnyEntity implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_GENERATOR")
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "MY_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
   private Integer id
```

and I have db sequence which have to use and which is running before insert.
Data saving properly but strange is that in db id is storing.
e.g
`3` and returning `2` to me. and for each run it is id generating like,

```
In dB | to me

  3   |  2

  5   |  4

  7   |  6

  9   |  8
```

Repository

```
   public interface repo implements JpaRepository<Entity, ID>{}
```

Dao Class

```
  public class dao {

      @autowired
      repo repo;

      method(){
          repo.save(entity);
      }}
```

Sequence used for table,

```
   CREATE SEQUENCE ORG_SEQ
   START WITH 1
   INCREMENT BY 1
   NO MAXVALUE
   NO CYCLE
   CACHE 24
```

I tried various solutions but nothing worth. Is am I doing any thing wrong or How can I do that. pls some one help.

Comment: Show the code that saves an entity

Comment: added repo and dao class code

Comment: And you are working with the returned entity of the save method?

Comment: yes.. i have relationship with other entity

Comment: Show the sequence definition and also the relationship ? Is the same sequence being used for persisting related entity also ?

Comment: seperate seq for seperate entity